# cmd command seporator broken in Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd

This is unrelated to Java, however the error occurs when I try to compile my code.

The semicolon in the command is causing Windows cmd to fail

Example

```
c:\>cd c:\windows <- no error

c:\>cd c:\windows; <- the semicolon is not being used a command separator but as part of the path
```

The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: In a Windows cmd semicolon is not a special character like in bash. The best you can do is use &.

Comment: Thanks, however I don't get to create the command. It is generated by Netbeans. I have put the resolution as an answer, adding a flag -J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true to Netbeans fixes the problem, however the command has not changed, but now it works?

Answer (score 1):

`cmd` doesn't use semicolon as a command separator. If you want to have two commands on the same line, you need to use `&` or `|` (depending on what you're trying to do).

`;` is used as an *argument* separator on Windows, but it's not supported by most applications. It has nothing to do with `cmd`, and `cmd` isn't supposed to deal with it (applications parse their command lines, not `cmd`). It also doesn't apply to `cmd` intrinsics like `cd` (`cd` is *not* an application).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory with a semicolon in the name try wrapping it in "double quotes."
Can't exactly verify your problem, but see below.

```
Z:\[]>dir
 Volume in drive Z has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CAC7-078B

 Directory of Z:\

11/27/2019  08:53    <DIR>          .
11/27/2019  08:53    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)    871243935744 bytes free

Z:\[]>md zz

Z:\[]>md zz;
A subdirectory or file zz already exists.

Z:\[]>md "zz;"

Z:\[]>dir
 Volume in drive Z has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CAC7-078B

 Directory of Z:\

11/27/2019  08:54    <DIR>          .
11/27/2019  08:54    <DIR>          ..
11/27/2019  08:54    <DIR>          zz
11/27/2019  08:54    <DIR>          zz;
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)    871243935744 bytes free

Z:\[]>cd zz;

Z:\zz;[]>cd ..\zz

Z:\zz[]>cd "..\zz;"

Z:\zz;[]>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved with the following

Adding -J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true to netbeans_default_options= in etc/netbeans.conf

The output from the compile command has not changed, however it now finds the directories???